# Start first page with `:right` css page rules?

Tags: html, css, princexml, css-paged-media

I have defined `@page :left` and `:right` margins like this:

```
@page :left {
  margin-left: 0.75in;
  margin-right: 0.25in;
}

@page :right {
  margin-right: 0.75in;
  margin-left: 0.25in;
}
```

When I print using Chrome it always seems to start the document with the `:left` rules.

Is there a way to have printing start with the `:right` rules?

I'm most interested in a solution for Chrome, but I'd also be interested in solutions for Prince.

Comment: Why not just swap the rule styles?  Just have `:left` have a wider right margin.

Comment: FYI: Prince appears to allow you to effectively swap the values of the two `:left` and `:right` rules: https://www.princexml.com/forum/topic/77/wrong-margins-on-the-page-left-and-page-right#15446

Comment: And that also seems to work in Chrome! If you want to write it up I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`page-break-before css property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before) to adjusts page breaks in both Chrome and Prince (apparently).

Answer (score 0):

CSS stands for "cascading style sheet" and the "cascading" means that it's read from top to bottom. If you simply switch the order of your statements, it should read right first.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the @page :right above the :left should do it.

```
@page :right {
  margin-right: 0.75in;
  margin-left: 0.25in;
}

@page :left {
  margin-left: 0.75in;
  margin-right: 0.25in;
}
```